# How to focus on a particular row in jquery

Tags: jquery-ui

I have a grid in my module. In this grid the first column "Vessel Name". In the vessel name is present in a alphabetical order. If I click any one of the vessel, one popup will open. After closing popup the grid is not refreshed properly. And the last data is present in first. I need to scroll.

So what I need is, After closing popup I need focus on the clicked vessel. How can I do this. I have more than 30 data in a grid. Based on rowIndx how can I achieve? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

Considering your table strucutre

```
<table class="grid-class">
<tr>
 <td>ele 1</td>
 ..
 <td>ele X</td>
</tr>
<tr class="active">  // the one you clicked,set active to this and remove to all other
 <td>ele 1</td>
 ..
 <td>ele X</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Firstly set a css(write your css based on your need) class active which highlight the row.Then try something like-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.grid-class tr').click(function() {
        $(this).sibling('tr').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```